# Update iOS icon badge number

Tags: ios, notifications, badge

I have a icon badge number update requirement. The app tracks tasks. I want the app to have a badge displaying the number of tasks due on each day. There are basically two cases when the badge number needs to be updated:

1. Midnight every day.
2. If new tasks are added or tasks are removed.

I know how to handle the second case. I can set badge number in the applicationResignActive func. However, the midnight automatic update is trick for me. To update the badge number, I need to call a func of the app to count the tasks that due on the day. However, in midnight, the app may be in all possible situations: foreground, background and not running. How can I do this? Thank you.

=====================================

To be clearer with my requirement, I would like the badge number to be updated everyday correctly, even the user never opens the app for a whole day or for consecutive several days. Also, I would try to avoid server side support because the app is a standalone app so far. Much appreciated for any help.

=====================================

Final update: I accepted Vitaliy's answer. However, his answer requires the app to be opened at least once every day. Otherwise, the event won't fire and the badge number cannot be updated.

Also, in my case, every time the app enters background event fires, I have to remove the existing notification and schedule a new one, with the up-to-dated badge number recalculated.

I am still interested in some way to handle the case that the app is not opened every day, how can you make sure the badge number is correct. So far, the easiest way is to setup some server and let it push notifications to the app regularly.

Comment: You should be more specific - reading this it sounds like you haven't read anything about how to do push notifications or background tasks.

Comment: I think that you can try apple push notification to finish the first case. Use the server side to update the tasks in your app. APN service tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: There is so far no server side programming for the app. The app is designed for used without server side support. So I would like to avoid moving some of the calculation logic to server side to purely serve the badge update purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `UILocalNotification`:

1. When app goes to background, calculate exact badge count number for nearest midnight
2. Schedule `UILocalNotification` at the nearest midnight with your calculated badge count
3. You will get notification at midnight, and app's badge count will be updated

Example code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Calculate nearest midnight or any other date, which you need
    NSDate *nearestMidnight = [self nearestMidnight];
    // Create and setup local notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.alertTitle = @"Some title";
    notification.alertBody = @"Some message";
    notification.fireDate = nearestMidnight;
    // Optional set repeat interval, if user didn't launch the app after nearest midnight
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    // Calculate badge count and set it to notification
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [self calculateBadgeCountForDate:nearestMidnight];
    [application scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: What about the user never opens the app for a day? What if the user never opens the app for continuous x days? Will the badge number still be updated correctly every day?

Comment: @QuangHà No I haven't tried Vitaliy's approach. However, by reading the code, I can see that it calls calculateBadgeCountForDate to get the next day's event count and assign to the notification. I suspect that if the user doesn't open the app for a whole day, the applicationDidEnterBackground method will not be called. So the badge number will remain the same. Only when the user opens the app once in a day, then the badge number will be updated. This is my understanding by reading the code. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Vitaliy Also, do I need to delete existing notification before schedule a new one? If user opens and closes the app several times a day, will your code add multiple notifications targeting for the same midnight?